# GPG error : Installation of Zcash in server

Tags: ubuntu, debian, zcash

I am installing Zcash on server(Ubuntu) by referring [zcash installation steps](https://z.cash/download.html)

But when I enter below command in terminal,got an error

> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
> Hit:2 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease                                                           
> Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                                                         
> Get:4 http://repo.stackdriver.com/apt stretch InRelease [2,100 B]                                                                               
> Hit:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease                                                                                               
> Hit:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release                                                                        
> Hit:7 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-wheezy InRelease                    
> Hit:8 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-monitoring-stretch InRelease                
> Hit:9 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-stretch InRelease        
> Hit:10 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-stretch-stable InRelease
> ............
>
> Err:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
>   404  Not Found
> Ign:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu cosmic/main Translation-en
> Ign:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu cosmic/main Translation-en_US
> Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu cosmic/main Translation-en_US.UTF-8
> Fetched 2,100 B in 6s (323 B/s)
>
> Reading package lists... Done
>
> W: GPG error: http://repo.stackdriver.com/apt stretch InRelease: The following signatures were invalid:B10FDCDCEC088467D0069F423C6E15887B190BD2
>
> W: The repository 'http://repo.stackdriver.com/apt stretch InRelease' is not signed.
>
> N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
>
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
>
> W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu cosmic Release' does not have a Release file.
>
> N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
>
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
> ```

What GPG what does the error means ?
How to validate GPG signature ?

Comment: The GPG error comes from http://repo.stackdriver.com/apt package repository. Whether they have published packages signed with a wrong key, or you don't have the proper GPG key to validate the signature (probably the second one).  Double-check all the steps provided on the link you include in your own question.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I will check & let you know